# Query that outputs the totals of two associated tables not returning totals correctly, why?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Hello I have the following db schema, 3 tables:

```
connected_accounts (fields: id, user_id, account_name)
contacts (fields: id, user_id, connected_account_id, type)
user_recommendations (fields: id, user_id, contact_id)
```

I'm trying to output a query that shows, per each connect_account record in the DB, totals of # of contacts and user_recommendations associated. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    ca.id, 
    ca.user_id, 
    ca.account_name,
    COUNT(c.id) AS Total
FROM connected_accounts ca
LEFT JOIN contacts c
     ON ca.id = c.connected_account_id
       AND c.contact_type = 'email'
WHERE ca.resource_type = 'calendar.readonly'
ORDER BY ca.id DESC
LIMIT 8
```

This is not working correctly... The desired output would look like this:

**RESULTS**

```
id | user_id | account_name | Total Contacts | Total User Recommendations
```

I haven't joined the UserRecommendations yet as my contacts join isn't working as desired.

What am I doing wrong in my query? thank you

UPDATED:

```
SELECT 
    ca.id, 
    ca.user_id, 
    ca.account_name,
    COUNT(c.id) AS 'Total Contacts',
    COUNT(pr.id) AS 'Total User Rec.'
FROM connected_accounts ca

LEFT JOIN contacts c
     ON ca.id = c.connected_account_id
       AND c.contact_type = 'email'

LEFT JOIN user_recommendations pr
     ON ca.id = pr.connected_account_id

WHERE ca.resource_type = 'calendar.readonly'
GROUP BY ca.id, ca.user_id, ca.account_name
ORDER BY ca.id DESC
LIMIT 8
```

UPDATED ABOVE.. The above updated query is returning the same # for `Total Contacts` & `Total User Rec` -- the number, which is the same for both is the right number for total contacts..  The `Total User Rec` is not being returned... why?

Comment: Just to clarify, does the `contact_type` field exist on `contacts`? And does `resource_type` field exist on `connected_accounts`? You have both of these in your query but not in the schema listing above.

Comment: Yes contact_type exists on contacts,,, and yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `GROUP BY`. Try this. Hope it helps.
Also, `LEFT JOIN` will have all the records from the `connected_accounts` table, is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
    ca.id, 
    ca.user_id, 
    ca.account_name,
    COUNT(c.id) AS Total
FROM connected_accounts ca
LEFT JOIN contacts c
     ON ca.id = c.connected_account_id
       AND c.contact_type = 'email'
WHERE ca.resource_type = 'calendar.readonly'
GROUP BY ca.id, ca.user_id, ca.account_name
ORDER BY ca.id DESC
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: That's much closer thank you but it is missing the `Total User Recommendations`